# A question on the dual of $l_\infty(X)$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Let $C(X)$ be the continuous functions on $X$ with sup norm and $l_\infty(X)$ be the bounded functions on $X$, also with the sup norm.

Suppose $\{g_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset C(X)$ is such that $g_n\to g$ pointwise, whence $g\in l_\infty(X)$.

Edit: I am assuming $\{g_n\}$ is uniformly bounded here.

**Does $g_n \to g$ weakly in $l_\infty(X)$?**

The motivation for this question is as follows:

For any functional $T\in l_\infty(X)^*$, $T\mid_{C(X)}$ corresponds to a Radon measure $\mu$ by the Riesz representation theorem. Thus, by DCT,

$$T(g_n) = \int g_n(x) d\mu(x) \to \int g(x) d\mu(x)$$

However, can we conclude that $\int g(x) d\mu(x) = T(g)$?

(What if we do this on Bounded Borel functions instead of $l_\infty(X)$?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First off, you cannot deduce that
$$(*)\qquad T(g_n)=\int_X g_nd\mu\to \int_X g d\mu $$
by the DCT under the sole assumption of $g_n\to g$ pointwise. Take for instance $X=[0,1]$ and $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure - you can easily construct a sequence of continuous functions which converges pointwise to $g=0$, but whose integrals do not converge to $0$.

You also need 
$$\exists f\in L^1(X):|g_n(x)|\leq |f(x)|\quad\text{for a.e.}\,x\in X,\;\forall n\in \mathbb{N} $$
This is for instance guaranteed if $\left\{g_n\right\}$ is uniformly bounded, i.e.  there is some constant $C>0$ such that $\|g_n\|_{\infty}\leq C$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Secondly, the answer to your first question is **no**.

Indeed, choose a sequence of distinct points $\left\{x_n\right\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subset X$ and take 
\begin{align*}F(g):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}g(x_n)2^{-n}
\end{align*}
The series converges for all $g$ bounded, and $F$ is linear and continuous on $\ell_{\infty}$, because if $\|g_k\|_{\infty}\to 0$ then
$$|F(g_k)|\leq \|g_k\|_{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}=\|g_k\|_{\infty}\to 0 $$ Now since $X$ is Hausdorff, let $\left\{U_n\right\}$ be a sequence of disjoint neighborhoods of $\left\{x_n\right\}$ and take a sequence of continuous functions $\left\{g_n\right\}$, satisfying the following properties: 
\begin{align*}g_n(x)&=0 \qquad \forall x\notin U_n \\
g_n(x_n)&=2^n\qquad \forall n\in \mathbb{N} \end{align*}
(such a sequence exists by the [Urysohn lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn%27s_lemma) since all compact Hausdorff spaces are normal).

Then for each $x\in X$, we have two options. Either $x\notin \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}U_n$, and then $g_n(x)=0$ for all $n$, or $x\in U_m$ for a unique $m\in \mathbb{N}$, and then $g_n(x)=0$ for all $n\neq m$. In both cases, $g_n(x)\to 0$, so $g_n\to 0$ pointwise. However,
$$ F(g_n)=2^n\cdot2^{-n}=1\not \to 0$$
and hence $g_n\not \to 0$ weakly.

EDIT: However, if you additionally assume that $\left\{g_n\right\}$ is uniformly bounded in $C(X)$, then **weak convergence in $\ell_{\infty}(X)$ does hold.**

Indeed, under this assumption, by the dominated convergence theorem we have 
$$\int_X g_n\,d\mu \to \int_X g\,d\mu $$
*for all Radon measures* $\mu$. By the Riesz Representation theorem, this means that for each $T\in l_{\infty}(X)^*$, the sequence $\left\{T(g_n)\right\}$ is convergent, and hence $\left\{g_n\right\}$ is weakly convergent in $l_{\infty}(X)$. It remains to prove that the weak limit is $g$. Suppose that $g_n\rightharpoonup h$, with $h\in l_{\infty}(X)$. Then for each $x\in X$, if $T_x\in l_{\infty}(X)$ is the evaluation functional
\begin{align*}T_x:l_{\infty}(X)&\to \mathbb{R}\\ 
f&\mapsto f(x)
\end{align*}
since $g_n\rightharpoonup h$ we have $T_x(g_n)\to T_x(h)$ for all $x\in X$, i.e. $g_n(x)\to h(x)$ for all $x\in X$. On the other hand since $g_n\to g$ pointwise we have $g_n(x)\to g(x)$ for all $x\in X$. Thus $g=h$, and $g_n\rightharpoonup g$ weakly. In particular, $T(g_n)\to T(g)$ for all $T\in l_{\infty}(X)^*$ and
$$T(g)=\int_X g\,d\mu $$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't understand the last part: "Since $T$ is a continuous linear functional... it is also weakly* continuous"  The norm topology is stronger than the $w^*$-topology - how did you conclude this?

Comment: @Merry It is wrong (it is only true for the weak topology, not the weak*). Also the entire second part of the answer is wrong since " $L^1$ " is meaningless since $X$ has no measure in it.  Also even if we put a measure on $X$ then $L^{\infty}(X)$ and $\ell_{\infty}(X)$ would still be different spaces so the argument is still useless. I am trying to correct this now.

Comment: @Merry I think this updated proof that pointwise convergence does not imply weak convergence in $\ell_{\infty}$ should be fine.

Comment: What happens if your $g_n$ are uniformly bounded? I actually meant to add this to the original question but it was a error on my part. Note that in this case if $g_n\to g$ pointwise, and $g$ is continuous, then weak convergence indeed does hold in $l_{\infty}$, as $\mu$ and $T$ coincide on $C(G)$.

Comment: Thanks! In your case, the limit point $g$ is also continuous (albeit the sequence is not bounded), so I am curious if it holds for bounded sequences.

Comment: If there is weak convergence then you are done, because $T$ is a (strongly) continuous linear functional, and hence weakly continuous: this is because the weak topology is by definition 'the weakest topology which makes all strongly continuous linear functionals continuous'. So if $g_n$ converges weakly to $g$, then $T(g_n)\to T(g)$.

Comment: No I mean, I only have pointwise convergence. I am not sure what you mean. Weak convergence is precisely what I am trying to prove. The question asks if the $\mu$ from $C(G)*$ coincides with $T$ at that point.

Comment: @Merry I've added a proof that under the assumption of uniform boundedness then weak convergence holds.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not sure this proof works. When you assume that $\{g_n\}$ is weakly convergent, you assume it converges to **something** weakly. However, in this case, we haven't yet shown that $g_n \to g$ weakly, simply that the net $\{Tg_n\}$ converges in $\mathbb{C}$ for each $T\in l_{\infty}(X)^*$

Comment: @Merry I assumed that $g_n\rightharpoonup h$ where $h$ is an arbitrary element of $\ell_{\infty}(X)$ and then proved that $h=g$ afterwards.. This is exactly the content of the last 5-6 lines of the proof